# Как преобразовать текстовый вывод print_r/из файла назад в массив?

Tags: php, массивы, преобразование

Хочу попробовать реализовать окно настроек с заполнением из массива. Нужно прочесть подобный файл и сформировать из него ассоциативный массив.

```
Array
(
    ['Технологические настройки'] => Array
    (
        ['Отправка запросов к модулям'] => Array
        (
            ['Модуль1'] => Array
            (
                    ['type']    =>'checkbox',
                    ['id']      =>'chb1',
                    ['name']    =>'chb1',
                    ['checked'] =>1,
            ),
            ['Модуль2'] => Array
            (
                   .....
            )
              
        )
    )
)
```

Вопрос в том как сохранить настройки в удобочитаемом виде, без json/serialize ? Чтобы открыть файл с подобным наполнением, откорректировать его и получить на форме новые элементы. В интернете есть несколько решений, но они для цифровых массивов, для ассоциативных не срабатывают.

Comment: то есть хотите создать себе проблему на ровном месте, а потом решать ее неделю?

Comment: Предложите вариант получше ? 1. Динамическое формирование списка параметров 2. Удобная настройка (добавление/удаление/изменение списка параметров)

Comment: yaml уже изобретен. ini-файлы изобретены еще раньше.

Comment: ini файлы 2 уровня вложения (я где-то видел блоки такого плана :[par1][par2]), на примере выше приведено 3 уровня. Yaml не рассматривал, пойду почитаю, спасибо.

Comment: а чем вам, собственно, не нравится JSON?) Его и в БД хранить можно, и в файле, можно легко бреобразовывать как на сервере, так и на клиенте.. читаемый внешний вид, не хуже print_r.. если задача состоит в том, чтоб красиво отобразить пользователю настройки при редактировании, то вообще какая разница что слать с сервера) Опишите пожалуйста проблему подробнее

Comment: уж лучше json с pretty_print вывести, его хоть обратно можно без проблем свернуть, а тут танцы с бубном обеспечены. print_r кроме как для отладочных целей никуда и не применяется, и уж точно, его автор не предполагал, что раз в полгода кто-то будет придумывать, как свернуть его обратно

Comment: Отображение настроек для пользователя - не проблема. Мне нужна настройка production/development, не хочу каждый раз открывать, изменять и сохранять файл. Или вот - веб-морда выступает в качестве интегратора между сервером 1С и софтом на ПК, где будет проводится форматирование ключей. Надо отключить то одну то другую сторону... и таких настроек накопится с десяток. JSON настройки в одну строку ужас, не говоря о модификации - вместо параметра вставить массив например. json отпадает, ini тоже. Не пробовал Yaml, но при беглом прочтении наверное то что нужно - данные файле хранятся структурно.

Comment: Отображение настроек в веб-форме будет формироваться динамически (вставляться чекбоксы, радиокнопки или списки) Как вариант рассматриваю кнопку Добавить с указанием типа элемента, а хранить тогда можно и в json.